# Event respond faster than semaphore?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

In a project I run into a case like this (On windows 7),

When several threads are busy (all my CPU cores are busy working), there'll be delay for a thread
to receive a semaphore (which is increased from 0 to 1). It may be as long as 1.5ms.

I solve this by cache a little things and increase the semaphore value earlier.

So to me, it seems signaling a semaphore is slow, it's not immediately received by threads (especially when CPU are busy), but if you signal it earlier before some thread begin to wait on it,, there' be no delay.

I once thought event is just a semaphore with maximum value of 1,,, well, now having met this case, I'm beginning to wonder if event is faster than semaphore at noticing threads to 'wake up'.

Sorry, I tried, but didn't come out with a demo,, I'm not very good at threading yet.

EDIT:
    Is it true that Event is faster than Semaphore on Windows?

Comment: Don't you mean you once thought a mutex was a semaphore with a maximum value of 1, not an event?

Comment: Yeah, mutex is more like it. But after you signal a event twice, two threads come and wait for it,, only one can get the signal,, so I feel event is also a little like it

Comment: You could just use a critical section. They're faster than events and mutex's as long as the spin lock doesn't time out.

Comment: I'm afraid the spin lock may affect other threads, spin lock will compete for CPU while many other threads are busy.

Comment: `Event` *might* be faster than `Semaphore`, but if it is it would be on the order of microseconds. The problem you describe can't explained by the difference in speed between those two primitives. But without a code example it's impossible to say what might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.5 milliseconds is not explained by just the overhead between different multithreading primitives.

To simplify, Threads have three states

- blocked
- runnable
- running

If a thread is waiting on a semaphore or an event, then it's blocked. When the event is signalled, it becomes runnable.

So the real question is, "When does a runnable thread actually run?" This varies according to scheduler algorithms, etc, but obviously it needs to run on a core, and that means nothing else can be "running" on that core at the same time. The scheduler will normally 'remove' the current running thread from a core when one of the following happens

- it waits on a semaphore/event, and so becomes 'blocked'
- It's been running continually for a certain time (time-based, or round-robin scheduling)
- *A higher priority thread becomes runnable.*

The 1.5 milliseconds is probably round-robin, or time-based scheduling. Your thread is runnable but just hasn't started yet. If the thread *must* start, and should boot out the current thread, then you can try to increase it's priority via `SetThreadPriority`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I seem to remember from "I don't remember whatever sources" that WIN32 semaphore blocked threads are scheduled FIFO, wile event and mutexes blocked thread LIFO. Coupled with your explanation, this justify the event's faster wake-up

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia That's not impossible ;-) The precise Windows thread scheduler algorithm is intentionally undocumented(!) to prevent apps relying on something that's liable to change dramatically between versions. Using documented ways of manipulating it (eg `SetThreadPriority`) is really the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread is waiting on a semaphore and it gets signaled, the thread will in my limited testing, become running in ~10us on a box that is not overloaded.

Signaling, and subsequent dispatching onto a core, will take longer if:

The signaled thread is in another process than any thread is preempts.

Running the signaled thread requires a thread running on another core to be preempted.

The box is already overloaded with higher-priority threads.

1.5ms must represent an extreme case where your box is very busy.

In such a case, replacing the semaphore with an event is unlikely to result in any significant improvement to overall signaling latency because the bulk of the work/delay required by the inter-thread signaling is tied up the in scheduling/dispatching, which is required in either case.